# How to succesfully wait for a function to end?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, concurrency, promise, async-await

I want to get the length of a song in youtube, but i cant make my program wait for my `get_link` function to end, even if i use async/await, my code will always return [Object, Promise]

```
async function get_link (song) {
    search(song, opts, function(err, results) {
        if(err) return console.log(err);
        return new Promise(getlink => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                getlink(results[0].link);
            }, 7000);
        })
    });
}

async function song_length (song) {
    return ytdl.getInfo(song);
}

async function main () {
    let link = await get_link("misery");
    console.log("Link: " + link);
    let len = await song_length(link);
    console.log("Len: " + len);
}
```

I get an error in song_length because "link" is not an url, its a promise.

Comment: An async function must always return a Promise. `get_link()` doesn't return anything (explicitely). It only performs `search()`, which is another async function. Well actually, this is not quite right. It _does_ return the last statement implicitely if you don't specify any. So, it does return `search()`. But it does it immediately, while `search()` is only starting its execution, therefore `search()` is seen as a pending Promise. It will never resolve for this reason.

Comment: Your get_link is wrong, wrap the whole thing inside the promise constructor, not just the setTimeout.

Comment: Also the `async` on the `song_length` is meaningless, even if `getInfo` is async.

Comment: @JeremyThille  There is no implicit return here, it will return undefined.  Or more specifically, a Promise that returns undefined.. :)

Comment: It will return a pending promise that will never resolve. It's not undefined. An async function always returns a Promise.

Comment: @JeremyThille  No, it will resolve, unless there is an error..  It will resolve with `undefined`..

Answer (score 1):

As I said in comments, an async function must always return a Promise. `get_link()` doesn't return anything (explicitely). It only performs `search()`, which is another async function.

Well actually, this is not quite right. An async function does return the last statement implicitely, if you don't specify any explicitely. So, it *does* return `search()`. But it does it immediately, while `search()` is only starting its execution, therefore `search()` is returned as a pending Promise that will never resolve.

```
async function get_link(song) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        search(song, opts, function(err, results) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(results)
            }
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: `It does return the last statement implicitly if you don't specify any`  Not here it wont,.  Your maybe getting mixed up with lambada function ->  `const x => x * x`  here x*x will get returned.

Comment: From experience, yes it does... Try it. Functions marked `async` do that. It took me a while to find out.

Comment: Try this in console, ->  `async function test() { var b = 'something' }; console.log('test =',await test());`

Comment: @Keith https://codepen.io/jeremythille/pen/GRqgKyr?editors=0010

Comment: What does the codePen prove??, you have a setTimeout you console logged..  What's that got to do with what test returned?, as test returned undefined.

Comment: Of course, because there's only sync things in your example :) Try with something async (that's what async functions are made for), it will return a Promise, even if you don't explicitely return anything. That is what my codepen proves.

Comment: It's nothing to do with it been async.  Even your fiddle returned a Promise that resolved to undefined.   In the console log, did you not see the Promise..?  In chrome, click on this, you should see something like -> `[[PromiseResult]]: undefined`..  The log entry is just that, your `console.log` inside the setTimeout.

Comment: That's exactly my point. And what I wrote in comments in the Codepen.

Comment: Your point is that, `search(),` got returned implicitly,  but it didn't.  `undefined` got returned..  Your solution for the OP is correct, but your logic on implicit return was wrong.   You don't do python as well do you, that uses implicit returns, but Javascript doesn't, apart from simple lambada functions anyway.

Comment: Ha. If I'm wrong, then why is OP surprised that their function returns a Promise instead of a value? `...my code will always return [Object, Promise] [...]  "link" is not an url, its a promise.`

Comment: Lambdas functions are just syntactic sugar. Async functions do implicit returns. If I can't, and if my codepen demonstration can't convince you of this either, then I guess we're done talking :) No need to waste our time

Comment: `async` functions always return a Promise,..  But what's that got to do with you claiming that the result of search will implicitly be returned?.

Comment: Your codePen, proved it didn't, it returned undefined inside the promise.   Your digging yourself into a hole here, and I'm not really sure why..  Javascript functions do NOT implicitly return the last statement.  It's ironic, I was all set to upvote you answer, but with the invalid statement in there, I can't.

Comment: @Keith quote from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Description) : `Async functions always return a promise.`

Comment: @Eldar  Cheers, but I don't think Jeremy wants to know, and will claim MDN have got it wrong because a setTimeout inside an async function in a fiddle proves it.